# max() function: how to get the item being iterated and pass to key=func()

Tags: python, python-2.7

I am learning to code in python.
My first self-assigned assignment is Dijkstra's algorithm
I was able make_graph and populate it but I am stuck in determining SSSP(source).

I am trying to use `min(list,key=func())` to get the least value item.
"key=func()":in another list with the same index of min value has to have value "not iterated yet"

How to pass current list item, the one being iterated to key fund () to check it has a corresponding value in check_list as "not Iterated yet".
If key=True will the min value be returned?

How key=func() works if func() returns a boolean value

Comment: Usually with `Dijkstra` you would use a min queue with `heapq`. Your method doesn't look like it would be very efficient

Comment: @jamylak
My method is my understanding of djikstra. After thinking for a while i decided to use deque..

 `queue_done.append(vertex.pop(vertex.index(min(vertex))))`

queue_done = no of nodes iterated
and 
vertex =sssp matrix

Comment: That doesn't look like it pops items in sorted order by edge weight, you might need to rethink your design. Go to page 199 of this: http://books.google.com/books?id=4cytGpIPYsAC&printsec=frontcover (page 205 is Dijkstra)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

just use `func`, drop the `()`:

```
min(list,key=func)
```

example:

```
>>> lis = [ '1', '2', '3', '4' ]
>>> def func(x):
...     return int(x)
... 
>>> min(lis, key=func) # each value from list is passed to `func`(one at a time)
'1'
```

In python `True` is equal to `1`, and `False` is equal to `0`, so if `func()` returns boolean values then actually your `min` function will be comparing just `1` and `0`.

```
>>> True == 1
True
>>> False == 0
True
```

Example:

```
>>> def func(x): return bool(x)
>>> lis = [ 1, [], 3, 4 ]
>>> min(lis, key=func) # bool([]) evaluated to False, ie 0
[]
>>> max(lis, key=func)
1
```

Another Example:

```
>>> lis  = [[4,5,6], [1,2], [13,1,1,1], [1000]]
>>> def func(x):
...     return len(x)  #comparisons are done based on this value
... 
>>> min(lis, key = func)
[1000]
#equal to
>>> min(lis, key = len)
[1000]
```

Comment: Maybe you should add `def func(x): return bool(x)`

Comment: But it does not return the value from the key. in your first example it is comparing the ascii values of strings and returning '1'.

Comment: @SreeramBoyapati it is not comparing the ascii values, it is comparing the `int` version of each string.

Comment: @SreeramBoyapati read the docs : http://wiki.python.org/moin/HowTo/Sorting#Key_Functions

Comment: @SreeramBoyapati I've added another example to make it a bit more clear.